# PHP in_array tempramental

Tags: php, arrays

Okay, in PHP

I have a big array of items stored in a file. It is serialized

The user selects what items they want to use and this creates another array, which is serialised and stored to a seperate file.

when the user returns to the selection area I take the data from both files and unserialise it, and use in_array to mark the users selections.

The first time I go into the selection area each day the selections aren't autofilled, but if I select them I can go away and come back as many times as I like and the selections I have chosen are autofilled, can anyone think of a reason for this.

Comment: Any chance you could add some code?

Comment: You have to explain better. What is the *selection area*? What do you mean with *each day*? Of course if you have not selected anything previously, it can't select anything, can it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the types of your selections using var_dump and choices. If they are not the same use false as a third parameter. It should be automatic but I have had issues before where I explicitly needed to use false.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have two problems.

1. Your script doesnt mark the selection.
2. You page is chached in the browser so after the first display it never queries the server.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. "The first time I go into the selection area each day"... where are you storing this selection file? If it's going into (say) `/tmp` on a Unix-server, odds are that the file's being cleaned up and removed for you.